# Asp.net mvc deserialize ajax.beginForm

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to pass my model, built in this form:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "FormContainer", HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "successFunc" }, new { id = "UpdateForm" }))
```

To this method:

```
public ActionResult SavePreset(DocumentFilterModel model, string name)
{
    //Do some magic
    return PartialView("Partial/FilterListPartial", model);
}
```

The point is that by default, this form will collect report presets, however i need to add and option to save preset in my DB, that is why `SavePreset` method is needed.

I have tried to use this script:

```
$("#SavePresetButton").on("click", function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("SavePreset", "Reports")',
    data: {
        name: $("#PresetNameEditor").val(),
        model: $("#UpdateForm").serialize()
    }
    }).success(function(result) {
        $("#FilterSettingsContainer").html(result);
    });
});
```

But i have encountered a problem, where i either get `null` in `DocumentFilterModel model` either (if change `model` parametr's type to `string`) can't deserialize it. Things i have tried:

```
var SettingsModel = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DocumentFilterModel>(model);
var a =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocumentFilterModel>(model);
```

By the way, (these filters located in separate partial view) i would like to keep my form as it is, because i still need to update my second partial view with lists of record, and `DocumentFilterModel` is too big to parse it manually.

Comment: You do not need to deserialize explicitly. Let the model binder does it's job. How does your `DocumentFilterModel` looks like ?  How are you rendering the input elements inside the form ?

Comment: The problem is that inside `DocumentFilterModel` is about 70+ properties (10 right inside an object and it contains 6 different object with 10 properties each), that is why parsing it manually is an option i want to avoid at any cost. Editors are created using `ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties` list, that is why i didn't include the code inside my form. And i can't use `submit`, because preset saving method must return partial view with filters and `submit` must return partial with records (the conflict inside `UpdateTargetId ` property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `serialize` method reads your form and generates a url encoded string with your input element names and values. So basically it will be a big querystring. When you pass that as the `data` property of the `$.ajax` call, jquery will use that for the request body (like FormData)

So when you try something like this

```
data:{
        name: $("#PresetNameEditor").val(),
        model: $("#UpdateForm").serialize()
     }
```

It it trying to send an object like this

```
{name: "Abc", model: "FirstName=Scott&Email=someEmail"}
```

You can see that you have a js object with 2 properties and the second property has all your input values in a query string format. The model binder cannot read this data and map to your `DocumentFilterModel` object!.

You cannot mix the result of `serialize` method to build a js object you want to send as data.

Simply use the result of `serialize` as the data property value of the ajax call and pass name in querystring.

```
$("#SavePresetButton").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("SavePreset", "Reports")?name='+$("#PresetNameEditor").val(),
        data: $("#UpdateForm").serialize()
    }).done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```